# softtimeout and timeout in celery tasks don't work

Tags: python, celery

I have a task that takes 20 seconds in average. I want to set soft and hard timeout for this task. I define it like this:

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True, timeout=100, soft_timeout=50)
def MYTASK(SOMEPARAMS):
     # MYTASK
```

But it doesn't work really. I test it with this params:

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True, timeout=1, soft_timeout=1)
def MYTASK(SOMEPARAMS):
     # MYTASK
```

But my tasks work correctly and them takes times over 1 seconds while it should never be done.

why timeout doesn't work?

**Edit**:
When I use 1 sec timeout in my log I see prints like this:

```
[2014-08-22 12:51:00,003: INFO/MainProcess] Task MYTASK[56002e72-a093-46c6-86cd-4c7b7e6ea7c3] succeeded in 15.549023876s: None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`time_limit`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.time_limit) and `soft_time_limit` parameters:

```
@task(time_limit=2, soft_time_limit=1)
def mytask():
    pass
```

Also note, that:

> Time limits do not currently work on Windows and other platforms that
>   do not support the SIGUSR1 signal.